# Custom wordpress page not showing any style

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using wordpress for literally handling posts and nothing else. I built a website and plugged it into wordpress and created a custom theme. The index page works fine and is style correctly, yet all the menu links where hard coded to contact.php, about.php etc but since changed them to /contactPage/ , /aboutPage/ and have added to the top of each of the pages this...

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: contactPage
*/
?>
```

And have changed the other pages accordingly, I have set the pages within the wp-admin and they see the pages. Yet when I navigate to them there are no styles applied, I have no idea what is going on? My CSS is located in the root along with the images, like I say index. php is showing everything fine, all fonts, images styles etc..but the inside pages show the content but no styling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue will be due to the way the stylesheets are linked in your header. Check out header.php and look for where the stylesheet is linked to, you will need to change them to be absolute URLs [get_template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri). You can confirm if that is the issue by opening the developer console and checking for 404 errors on your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the improper template assignment inside the pages. Please follow the steps to correct this.

1. `Dashboard` > `Pages` > select your page.
2. In the Page Attributes Meta Box select the corresponding template from Templates select box.
3. Update the page.

This may solve your problem.